# Internal server error: supabaseUrl is required. (Vite and Sveltekit)

Tags: javascript, environment-variables, svelte, sveltekit, supabase

I've been trying to add environment variables to my db.js file which connects to a Supabase database. When I pass the URL and key as a string it works perfectly but when I try to add environment variables it gives me this message: "Internal server error: supabaseUrl is required."

db.js

```
import { createClient } from '@supabase/supabase-js'
import { PUBLIC_SUPABASE_URL, PUBLIC_SUPABASE_ANON_KEY} from '$env/static/public';

console.log(PUBLIC_SUPABASE_URL);

const supabase = createClient(
  PUBLIC_SUPABASE_URL,
  PUBLIC_SUPABASE_ANON_KEY
) 


export default supabase;
```

Comment: does the logging work?

Comment: @cSharp It returns undefined 

Comment: I think you need the [Environment plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vite-plugin-environment)

Comment: Are you sure you have the `.env` file at the root of your directory? The code looks correct.

Comment: @ShrijiKondanElangovan Ahhh you're a lifesaver! It was in my src directory the whole time!

Comment: Haha, it happens!

Answer (score 1):

The code looks correct. Move/add the `.env` file at the root of the project directory.